# Distributing a binary utility in setuptools

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, distutils

I have a command-line program (`foo`) written in an esoteric programming language.  I'd like to distribute this program as part of an existing python package that uses setuptools.  `foo` should appear in the user's path and be executable from the command line, much like the behavior of distutil's [scripts](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts) or setuptools' [entry_points](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation).

It's feasible for me to cross-compile the program for every platform and then build a different egg for each platform with a platform-specific binary of `foo`.  The problem is, I don't know how to convince setuptools to copy the binary to a platform-appropriate place on the target system.

For example, I tried using the `scripts` directive:

```
setup(
...
scripts=["foo"]
...
)
```

but it appears setuptools doesn't like a "script" with non-utf8 data.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

I could declare it as a resource, but that wouldn't put it in the user's path.

How do I ship a binary command-line utility as part of a python package?

Comment: I've just answered this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/72946687/3160967

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution was as follows:

- Create a wrapper module `foowrapper`.
- `foowrapper` contains `foo` (but renamed to `foo_bin`) and a new script called `foo`, contents below:

.

```
 #!python
 file = __file__
 import os.path
 cmd = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"foo_bin")
 import subprocess
 subprocess.call([cmd] + sys.argv[1:])
```

- Update setup.py to contain foowrapper, foo, and foo_bin

.

```
setup(
  ...
  package_data={
    'foowrapper':['foo_bin']
  },
  packages=['foowrapper],
  scripts=['foowrapper/foo']
  ...
)
```