# How to extend a python package by binary executables?

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, distutils

My package is written almost entirely in python. However, some functionality is based on executables that are run within python using [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). If I set up the package locally, I need to first compile the corresponding C++ project (managed by CMake) and ensure that the resulting binary executables are created in the bin folder. My python scripts then can call these utilities.

My project's folder structure resembles the following one:

```
root_dir
- bin 
   - binary_tool1
   - binary_tool2
- cpp
   - CMakeLists.txt
   - tool1.cpp
   - tool2.cpp
- pkg_name
   - __init__.py
   - module1.py
   - module2.py
   - ...
LICENSE
README
setup.py
```

I now consider to create a distributable python package and to publish it via [PyPi/pip](https://pypi.org/). I therefore need to include the build-step of the C++ project into the packaging procedure.

So far, I create the python package (without the binary "payload") as described in [this tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/). I now wonder how to extend the packaging procedure such that the C++ binary files are distributed along with the package.

Questions:

- Is `setuptools` designed for such a use-case at all?
- Is this "mixed" package approach feasible at all or are binary compatibility issues to be expected?

I believe that the canonical approach to extend a pure-python package with C code is to create "binary extensions" (e.g. using [distutils](https://docs.python.org/3/library/distutils.html), or as described [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-binary-extensions/)). In this case, the functionality is provided by executables, and not by wrappable C/C++ functions. I would like to avoid redesigning the C++ project to create binary extensions.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Related, possibly dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686838/distributing-a-binary-utility-in-setuptools

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

I found a number of half-answers to this but nothing complete, so here goes.

#### Quick and easy (single-platform)

I believe you'll need to remove the dash from your package name. The rest of this answer assumes it's been replaced with an underscore.

1. Starting with your directory structure, create a copy of bin under pkg_name (or move bin there). The reason for that is, if you do not, you will end up installing files into your python folders `site-packages/pkg_name` and `site-packages/bin` instead of having it all under `site-packages/pkg_name`.

Your minimal set of files needed for packaging should now be as follows:

```
- pkg_name/
  - __init__.py
  - module1.py
  - module2.py
  - bin/
    - binary_tool1
    - binary_tool2
- setup.py
```

2. To call your binary executable from the code, use a relative path to `__file__`:

```
def run_binary_tool1(args):
    cmd = [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'bin', 'binary_tool1')] + args
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, ...)
    ...
```

3. In setup.py, reference your binaries in addition to your package folder:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='pkg_name',
    version='0.1.0',
    package_data={
        'pkg_name':['bin/binary_tool1','bin/binary_tool2']
    },
    packages=['pkg_name']
)
```

4. Do yourself a favor and create a Makefile:

```
# Makefile for pkg_name python wheel

# PKG_NAME and VERSION should match what is in setup.py
PKG_NAME=pkg_name
VERSION=0.1.0

# Shouldn't need to change anything below here

# determine the target wheel file
WHEEL_TARGET=dist/${PKG_NAME}-${VERSION}-py2.py3-none-any.whl

# help
help:
    @echo "Usage: make <setup|build|install|uninstall|clean>"

# install packaging utilities (only run this once)
setup: pip install wheel setuptools

# build the wheel
build: ${WHEEL_TARGET}

# install to local python environment
install: ${WHEEL_TARGET}
    pip install ${WHEEL_TARGET}

# uninstall from local python environment
uninstall:
    pip uninstall ${PKG_NAME}

# remove all build artifacts
clean:
    @rm -rf build dist ${PKG_NAME}.egg-info
    @find . -name __pycache__ -exec rm -rf {} \; 2>/dev/null

# build the wheel
${WHEEL_TARGET}: setup.py ${PKG_NAME}/__init__.py ${PKG_NAME}/module1.py ${PKG_NAME}/module2.py ${PKG_NAME}/bin/binary_tool1 ${PKG_NAME}/bin/binary_tool2
    python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal
```

4. Now you're ready to roll:

```
make setup  # only run once if needed
make install # runs `make build` first

## optional:
# make uninstall
# make clean
```

and in python:

```
import pkg_name
pkg_name.run_binary_tool1(...)
...
```

#### Multi-platform

You'll almost certainly want to provide more info in your `setup()` call, so I won't go into detail on that here. More importantly, the above creates a wheel that purports to be universal but really is not. This might be sufficient for your needs if you are sure you will only be distributing on a single platform and you don't mind this mismatch, but would not be suitable for broader distribution.

For multi-platform distribution, you could go the obvious route and create platform-specific wheels (changing the `--universal` flag in the above Makefile command, etc).

Alternatively, if you can compile a binary for every platform, you could packages all of the binaries for all platforms in your one universal wheel, and let your python code figure out which binary to call (for example, by checking `sys.platform` and/or other available variables to determine the platform details).

The advantages of this alternative approach are that the packaging process is still easy, the platform-dynamic code is some simple python, and you can easily reuse the same binary on multiple platforms provided that it actually works on those platforms. Now, I would not be surprised if the "all-binaries" approach is frowned on by at least some if not many, but hey, python users often say that developer time is king, so this approach has that argument in its favor-- as does the overall idea of packaging a binary executable instead of going through all the brain damage of creating a python/C wrapper interface.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas! That's indeed useful. Note: I fixed the pkg_name in my original post, the dash indeed is not a valid character for a package name.

Comment: I think by now that the recommended and most portable way is to wrap the C/C++ project (e.g., using Cython), as you also have mentioned in your answer. I have tried it [myself](https://pypi.org/project/cyminiball/) – certainly a good alternative for small to midsize C/C++ projects. Distributing home-brewed binaries is a practical alternative too, but creates a somewhat uneasy feeling :)

Comment: @normanius not quite the same, but related: https://simonwillison.net/2022/May/23/bundling-binary-tools-in-python-wheels/ or https://pypi.org/project/playwright/#files

Comment: How does this gel with e.g the advice given regarding package data files here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028000/how-to-read-a-static-file-from-inside-a-python-package? I.e. they say not to assume a file structure exists, not to use __file__ etc, but to use things like pkg_resources. Because package files might be all bundled up together in wheels or zips or whatever. What would be the idea there? Read the bytes of the binary data file and re-write the binary to some temporary directory so it can be executed?